# Mapping Eigenvectors to Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have the following basic linear algebra question:

Let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ be a set eigenvectors and $\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}$ be the eigenvalues of a linear operator $A$, i.e.
$$
Av_i=\lambda_iv_i.
$$

We define a mapping $f:Span(\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\})\rightarrow Span(\{\lambda_1,..,\lambda_n\})$, such that 
$$
f(v_i)=\lambda_i.
$$

My question: Can $f$ be a nonlinear functions? If so, can we construct an example where $f$ is quadratic (in for example 2D)?

Comment: You have a number of typos here.  Do not confuse eigenvectors with eigenvalues.  You should have $Av_i = \lambda_i v_i$, which is a vector, not $A\lambda_i$ which is an operator.  Next, $f$ maps eigen*vectors* to eigen*values*, not the other way around as in your title.  Now... as for your question about $f$... it is not going to be a linear function... in fact... $f(v_i+v_j)$ might not even be defined since $v_i+v_j$ isn't necessarily in the domain of the function.  According to your definition, $f$ is a function from a finite set $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$... not a function from a vector space.

Comment: @JMoravitz  Thanks for pointing out! Tried to edit my question.

Comment: With your latest edit... what do you mean by the span of eigenvalues?  You mean the set of all real numbers (or whatever your scalar field is)?  Even then... the associated eigenvalue to $v_1$ is the same as the associated eigenvalue to $2v_1$.  Suppose $Av_1 = \lambda_1 v_1$.  Well then, $A(2v_1) = 2 (Av_1) = 2(\lambda_1 v_1) = \lambda_1(2v_1)$.  So, $f(v_1+v_1) = \lambda_1 \neq \lambda_1+\lambda_1 = f(v_1)+f(v_1)$ so $f$ cannot be linear so long as there is a nonzero eigenvalue.  It also is not clear what $f(v_1+v_2)$ would be in the event that $v_1$ and $v_2$ have different eigenvalues.

Comment: I think, the main problem here is that you haven't actually defined $f$. You have only specified $f$ evaluated at the $v_i$. The question is: How do you define e.g. $f(v_1 + 4v_2)$? The answer to your question depends on this. If you really only specify $f(v_i)$ on the finite set of points $v_1, \dots, v_n$, then yes, $f$ can be a nonlinear function, in general.

Comment: @Sam not only can it *be* a nonlinear function, it will *always be* a nonlinear function.  See below.

Comment: @JMoravitz Okay. Suppose that we are working in Hilbert spaces and that my operator is hermitian. Then I can write $f(v_i)=\sum_{j\in\{1,\ldots, n\}}<v_i, Av_j><v_i,v_j>/<v_i, v_i>$ (with $v_j$ as basisvectors), right? For eigenvectors $v_i$ this will give $f(v_i)=\lambda_i$.  So let me formulate my question differently. Can we construct an operator $A$ in such a way that $f$ is in a functional form that we want, for example, quadratic?

Answer (score 1):

A linear combination of eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue will again be an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue.  The set of all eigenvectors with a particular eigenvalue is a subspace of the vectorspace called an eigenspace.

As such, your $f$ cannot be linear (*except in the trivial case where $A$ is the zero operator*) since you would otherwise for $\lambda_i\neq 0$ you would have had $f(\alpha v_i)=\lambda_i \neq \alpha \lambda_i$ for every $\alpha\neq 1$.

Further, your function fails to be adequately defined in general as a nontrivial sum of eigenvectors from different eigenspaces is not an eigenvector.  For instance, let $Av_1=\lambda_1 v_1$ and $Av_2=\lambda_2v_2$ where $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$ and neither $v_1$ nor $v_2$ the zero vector.  Then we have $A(v_1+v_2)=A(v_1)+A(v_2)=\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2=\lambda_1(v_1+v_2)+(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)v_2$ which is not a scalar multiple of $v_1+v_2$ since $(v_1+v_2)$ is linearly independent to $v_2$.  As such, it is not defined what $f(v_1+v_2)$ should be.

Your original function before the edit was at least properly defined, however you were asking questions about if it were a linear function which is not applicable as the domain was not a vector space but rather a finite set of eigenvectors.